# wordpress category drop down select link broken

Tags: javascript, wordpress, select, hyperlink, dropdown

I have a blog category drop down select list on my wordpress blog, the following code creates a link for the categories in the list:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChange() {
            if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); 
?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            } 
        }
        dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
        -->
    </script>
```

I think I need to edit the JavaScript so that when I select the "All Posts" option it will link to www.website.com/blog. the 'value' for "All posts" is 0. I tried this but it breaks all the links for the categories and doesnt fix the problem:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChange() {
            if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); 
?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            } elseif( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value == 0 ){
                location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>blog";
            }
        }
        dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
        -->
    </script>
```

heres the html output incase its needed:

```
<select name='cat' id='cat' class='postform' >
    <option value='0'>Show all posts</option>
    <option value='-1'>Select category</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1">Uncategorized</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="8">Blog</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own... working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value == 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>blog";
        } 
        else if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        } 
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    -->
</script>
```